# Is it possible to make prompt-function work with -XNoImplicitPrelude?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I have a project that uses a custom Prelude, however it seems to conflict with the prompt function I have in `~/.ghci`. Simple example:

```
$ ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude
GHCi, version 8.2.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/refold/etc/ghci
> :set prompt-function \ms _ -> ms

<interactive>:1:19: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘String’

<interactive>:1:30: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Int’

<interactive>:1:37: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘IO’

<interactive>:1:40: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘String’
```

Is it possible to make both `-XNoImplicitPrelude` and `:set prompt-function` work together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `String`, `Int`, `IO`, and whatever is necessary, back in scope. If `Prelude` is not available (because of using `base-noprelude`), these types can be found in their own modules:

```
> import Data.String (String)
> import Data.Int (Int)
> import System.IO (IO)
> import Text.Show (show)
> import Control.Applicative (pure)
> :set prompt-function \ms n -> pure (show (ms, n))  -- [String] -> Int -> IO String
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, but my project uses `base-noprelude` and the `Prelude` from `base` clashes with the one in my project. For some reason it doesn't work with `PackageImports` either. Ideally there would be a way to import stuff just for the prompt function scope, like local imports in OCaml.

Comment: The types are also exported in other modules. I updated my answer.

Comment: OK thanks, if I put something like `:m - Data.String Data.Bool Data.List Data.Eq Data.Function Data.Int System.IO Text.Show Control.Monad` after `:set prompt-function` in my `~/.ghci` I can sort of simulate local imports and get a clean prompt without noise.